# WordPress redirect issue?

Tags: wordpress

I have two WP installtion on a domain.

Root: 
`http://www.zbodysculpt.com`

Subsite:
`http://www.zbodysculpt.com/zbodydev/`

The problem is with the naviation links for `zbodydev`? They always redirect to the root site. They must navigate to the pages of subsite `zbodydev`? Any help about solving it?

Answer (score 0):

Go to `Settings` -> `General` in your dashboard and check that both `WordPress URL` and `Site URL` point to `http://www.zbodysculpt.com/zbodydev/`.

Comment: also if you want to completletly move the file to other domain need to chage  the url in database  with taht domain name

Comment: That's the same value that gets changed.